# How do I load a method thats in a class from a uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

I am trying to pass a uitextfield string from a view controller over to a method in a nsobject class... if you could please explain how I do this that would be great.

So far I have done the following however still getting lots of errors.

```
NSObject Class dbAccess.h
- (void)passCode:(NSString *)passedCode;

NSObject Class.m
- (void)passCode:(NSString *passedCode {
     myString = passedCodeVaraibel; //myString declared in .h
}
```

//... other code to initialize the database. with myString or something to that effect even though this is probably wrong this is why im asking the question

```
    viewController.m
    //pass myCode textfield string when uitableviewcell is selected.

[dbAccess.passCode myCode.text];
```

I know this is not right because its not working :) but I hope it adds more detail as to what I am trying to do.

Comment: that's a quite vague question, if you could edit the question to give more detail, it would be useful.  do you mean a class method in NSObject? which method?  how familiar are you with objective-c and iOS programming?

Comment: updated with more detail Hope you understand.

Comment: The call should be 

[dbAccess passCode:myCode.text];

Comment: with regards to my
` (void)passCode:(NSString *)passedCode {`
what should the contentence of this method look like? just like what I had up in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard objective-c convention would request that you change the method name to `setPassCode:`, however `passCode:` works perfectly fine.

i assume this code isn't compiling,
to correctly invoke a method, you use the following syntax (several examples):

```
[target action:argument];
[target action:arg1 anotherParameter:arg2];
[target action]
```

if you want to set a value, obviously you want to pass in that value as a parameter

```
// DBAccess.m
- (void)setPassCode:(NSString *)newPassCode {
   myString = newPassCode; // myString defined as ivar in .h
}


dbAccess = [[DBAccess alloc] init]; 
// …
[dbAccess setPassCode:textField.text];
```

Comment: Thankyou, This clears it up I have read this before but forgotten and having so much stuff jumbling around in my head takes me a few goes to get things sorted. Thanks for the example I have set it all up in my project but I'm getting an error that I am going to look into now, saying that my  method is undeclared even though I have it declared in my .h file.

Comment: this is the error
Its staying my method is undeclared, then it has this under it

 expected ';' before ':' token

Comment: what a muppet.. I figured out I was trying to use the method inside another one I had made.. DUH! so moved it out of that and everything worked fine. thanks alot :)